# Why in JavaScript is (super.__proto__ === this.__proto__) true?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It seems that in JavaScript (ES6) Classes `super.__proto__ === this.__proto__`.

Can you explain why this is the case? The behaviour seems consistent across different browsers, so I suspect this is specified somewhere in the spec.

Consider the following code:

```js
class Level1 {
    myFunc() {
        console.log('Level1');
    }
}

class Level2 extends Level1 {
    myFunc() {
        console.log('Level2');
    }
}

class Level3 extends Level2 {
    myFunc() {
        console.log('Level3 BEGIN ' + Math.random()); 
        super.__proto__.myFunc();
        console.log(super.__proto__ === this.__proto__);
        console.log('Level3 END'); 
    }
}

const foo = new Level3();
foo.myFunc();
```

I would have expected that `super.__proto__.myFunc();` would call the function `myFunc()` of class `Level1` and that `super.__proto__ !== this.__proto__`. Instead `super.__proto__.myFunc();` actually calls `myFunc()` of class `Level3` (it calls itself) and then on the second invocation it calls `myFunc()` of class `Level2`. This is perfectly comprehensible if `super.__proto__ === this.__proto__` which the code demonstrates.

Can you explain the reason why `super.__proto__ === this.__proto__` in this example? If possible, please also provide references to the relevant section of the spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object.prototype.__proto__` is a property with a getter<sup>[1]</sup>. It operates on its `this` value. There is no actual `super` object to be a `this` value (you couldn’t write `Object.getPrototypeOf(super)`), just a `super` way of looking up properties, so `this.__proto__` and `super.__proto__` mean the same thing as long as `__proto__` isn’t also defined anywhere lower on the prototype chain.

Compare:

```js
class Parent {
    get notProto() {
        return this instanceof Child;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    test() {
        console.log(super.notProto);
    }
}

new Child().test();

// bonus: [1]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__'));
```

Comment: I already suspected that this had something to do with `__proto__` actually being accessor functions on `Object.prototype` and operating on their `this` value. But I just coudn't imagine that `super` was  actually specified to work this way. I thought of `super` being roughly equivalent to `this.__proto__.__proto__`, so `super.__proto__` would have been equivalent to `this.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` which would have exhibited the behaviour I was expecting. Do you know, where in the spec the exact behaviour of `super` is specified?

Comment: @JensMoser: I'll find it in a bit, but imagine normal uses of `super`, like `super.setFoo('bar')`. You wouldn't want that operating on a prototype instead of the instance.

Comment: @georg I know that `__proto__` is an accessor property on `Object.prototype`. When I asked for a reference to the spec, I meant a reference to the exact behaviour of the `super` keyword in conjunction with `__proto__`. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Ry- Yes, I simplified a bit. My exact understanding of `super.setFoo('bar')` would be, that it is equivalent to `this.__proto__.__proto__.setFoo.call(this, 'bar')`. So, `super`automatically invokes functions with the correct `this`.

Comment: @JensMoser `super.__proto__` (in that method of the `Level3` class) is exactly equivalent to `Reflect.get(Object.getPrototypeOf(Level3.prototype), "__proto__", this)`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that explains in code form what Ry- expressed as text in his answer. I'd still appreciate a reference to the relevant section of the standard, if someone knows, where this is specified. Btw: Did you delete your comment which Ry- is refering to in comment #2?

Comment: @JensMoser http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.prototype.__proto__ should do? Yes, we deleted a few comments related to my mistaken edit.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. I'd like to add section 12.3.5 of the standard [http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-super-keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-super-keyword) which specifies the exact semantics of the super keyword.